# Is there a Hindi translation for Patanjali Yog Sutras and Vyasa's commentary on Sutras?

Tags: yoga, yoga-sutras, patanjali

I am looking for a hindi translation for Patanjali Yog Sutras and Vyasa's commentary on Sutras. Is there a Hindi translation? If there, could someone provide to me the translation or tell where to look for it?

Comment: Check this 
 [link.](https://archive.org/details/Patanjala_Yoga_Darsana_With_Vyasabhashya_Bhojavritti_Their_Hindi_Translation_Swami_Vijnanashram_1932/page/n19/mode/2up) Archive.org contains a large collection of hindu scriptures so from nxt time u can search there :)

Comment: Thanks for the link and info.